# AutoExposureLock resetting after calling takePicture()

Tags: android, camera

I'm having a problem with the exposure lock in the Android Camera.Parameters class. I'm able to lock the exposure before taking a picture, but upon calling `camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback)` the exposure starts auto-adjusting again.

Also, `getAutoExposureLock()` still returns `true` even though the preview and the final saved images show adjusted exposure.

The Android documentation says the exposure lock won't be changed by taking a picture: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setAutoExposureLock(boolean)

What am I missing?

Comment: this is happening on Samsung devices

Comment: Seeing the same on Nexus 5 and Google Glass.

Comment: Same problem on Nexus 6 & Samsung Galaxy S3. So far haven't found any workaround. Please share if you found any. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I managed to lock exposure compensation on my Galaxy S4

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Then in each `takePicture` callback I basically reset the lock to true

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

This manages to do *something*. All images captured are almost equally bright. Changing `exposureCompensation` has no effect, but when changing ISO the exposure time is automagically adjusted.

I'll dig some more into this and update this post accordingly.

Comment: mCamera.setParameters(parameters) did the trick for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. That's because `camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback)` stops the preview; you must call `camera.startPreview();` to continue previewing.

Answer (score 0):

I've come accross this myself, I'm assuming its an API error as it works the same for me as for you. Unless you have managed to fix it in the meantime? Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the lock to true in `takePicture` callback doesn't work well on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3. It makes situation a bit better, but still produces images with quite different brightness. Exif inside those jepgs confirm that `exposure time` varies from 1/120 sec to 1/400 sec.

I also noticed that some jpegs have similar `exposure time` (1/120 sec) but different `brightness` value saved in exif. So, my was guess that the image post-processor is the game breaker.

I've dumped all camera parameters via `native_getParameters`, found image correction parameters and set them all to `5`. Those parameters are:

```
set("min-brightness", 5);
set("max-brightness", 5);

set("contrast", 5);
set("min-contrast", 5);
set("max-contrast", 5);

set("max-saturation", 5);
set("min-saturation", 5);
set("saturation", 5);
```

Now output is much better. Images almost equally bright. All of 500 test images have `exposure time` = 1/120 ± 1 (rarely 1/125) and `brightness` = 5 ± 0.1.

Comment: How did you determine that the parameter value should be 5?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on S3. I ended putting those line at the begining of the callback:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    //Relock the camera for S3 device
    camera.startPreview();
    UnLockCamera(camera);
    LockCamera(camera);
    // your code
```

With the two functions below

```
public void LockCamera(Camera camera){
    //stop auto white balance and auto exposure lock
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    if (params.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
        params.setAutoExposureLock (true);
    }
    if (params.isAutoWhiteBalanceLockSupported()) {
        params.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
    }
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
public void UnLockCamera(Camera camera){
    //stop auto white balance and auto exposure lock
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    if (params.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
        params.setAutoExposureLock (false);
    }
    if (params.isAutoWhiteBalanceLockSupported()) {
        params.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(false);
    }
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```